# Outlook AppointmentItem property changes

Tags: c#, office-interop, outlook-addin

Is there a way to know when the value of certain properties of an AppointmentItem change?  I have a custom task pane, and if the appointment is both marked as an all day event and the status is "Out of Office" then I want the task pane to appear.  If it's not, then the task pane would be hidden.

Is there some type of event I can watch for and toggle the visibility dynamically as they update the AppointmentItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use `AppointmentItem.PropertyChange` event.